Example of closed non-exact torsion differential form on variety
I asked this question some time ago on MSE and received close to no interest. I feel it is appropriate for this site:
I am interested in finding a particular example. I would like to find a variety (analytic or algebraic over $\mathbb C$) such that the de Rham sequence is not exact and the variety admits a germ of a differential 1-form $\alpha\ne0$ such that it is torsion, $d\alpha=0$ and $\alpha\ne df$. By torsion I mean that the germ is annihilated by a regular element of the stalk of the structure sheaf.
From a paper of H. Reiffen I know that if the polynomial $x^p+y^q+y^{q - 1}x$ in $\mathbb C^2$ is irreducible at 0, then the analytic de Rham sequence is not exact in degree $1$ ($p\ge 4$, $q\ge p + 1$). However, I have not been able to utilizes this class of examples to produce a closed non-exact torsion 1-form.
Does someone have an idea of how to approach this or perhaps even an example in mind? Or is such an example impossible?
I am aware of some of the literature regarding the existence of torsion $1$-forms, for example:
"Torsion and cotorsion in the sheaf of Kähler differentials on some mild singularities" by D. Greb & S. Rollenske
"On torsion Kähler differential forms" by D. Bourqui & J. Sebag.
I know that any such example — if it exists — must be a variety that is not holomorphically contractible to a point, as the de Rham sequence is exact for holomorphically contractible varieties
